# Is it safe to let Piracy build up in systems with Protection, not Suppression?

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris, specifically version 2.2 Le Guin, is a nearby starbase's Protection value enough to prevent ill effects from Piracy, or is there a benefit to assigning ships to provide Piracy Suppression as well?

Take this system for instance:
[image: In-game screenshot showing Piracy, Piracy Suppression, and Protection]

This system isn't being patrolled by any fleets, and no fleets are nearby, so it doesn't have any Piracy Suppression. As a result its Piracy is slowly building up.

But because it's right next door to a fortified border post, this system has a huge amount of Protection - easily enough to dwarf the listed "Max Piracy", and in fact more than the actual value of the trade route. If I understand correctly, that means its full Trade Value will be delivered no matter how much Piracy is allowed to build.

My question is, what do I stand to lose (in terms of events or other effects) from not assigning a fleet to patrol this system?

Answer (score 6):

You're perfectly fine. Patrols and star bases are equal in terms of piracy suppression. Piracy effects are 0.

Answer (score 1):

Stations provide adequate protection, but only up to a certain level. Once the trade flow surpasses the current protection ceiling you will get piracy in that system and will need to either add more protection from stations or a patrol.